# Why layout_weight doesnt work properly inside the RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

I tried to display two ImageView verticaly  inside a RelativeLayout, each imageView has 50% as weight, but the display just one ImageView is displayed.

**Code :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_board"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:weightSum="2">

<ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<ImageView  android:id="@+id/imageView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

please Help!

Comment: `layout_weight` only works with `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_weight` is not an attribute of `RelativeLayout` it is an attribute of `LinearLayout`. So you can change the parent layout to `LinearLayout` or you can use [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

code snippet

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Changing your root `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` solve your problem and to use `layout_weight` attribute in your code you've to use **LinearLayout** instead of using the **RelativeLayout** as ViewGroup. There's no `layout_weight` attribute in RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Add Linearlayout below  RelativeLayout. weightSum is the attribute of LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_board"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```